# How to give various widths to various other divs using js

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, animation

I'm trying to get various progress bars for my website that load at equal speeds but of different lengths. I have tried this code but it isn't working

```js
var prog = document.getElementsByClassName("prog");
var c = 0;
var ski = [50, 40, 35, 25, 32, 33, 20, 25];
var j;
var t = 0;

function inc() {
  if (t == ski[c]) {
    clearTimeout(ty);
    t = 0;

  } else {
    t++;
    prog[c].style.width = t + "%";
  }
}

function ani() {
  for (j = 0; j < ski.length; j++) {
    var ty = setTimeout(inc, 30);
    c = j;
  }
}

ani();
```

The `ski` array is the length of percent for div to load after animation is complete considering 50% width as a full length of a progress bar. `prog` is an array of divs of small height and long width.

Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're setting the width of each item to `t` which is an index in your case. You could try to set it to `ski[t]`.

Basically you're setting each one to `1%`, then `2%`, etc.

Comment: no that is not the case , see t is an increasing variable which will reach ski[c], where 'c' belongs to each individual div and will increase the width %..

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be massively over-complicating the problem. You can simply loop through each of the `.prog` elements in the `prog` array, then set their width. If you want the change to be animated, set `transition: width` in the CSS of those elements, like this:

```js
window.addEventListener('load', function() {
  var prog = document.getElementsByClassName("prog");
  var ski = [50, 40, 35, 25, 32, 33, 20, 25];

  function ani() {
    for (i = 0; i < prog.length; i++) {
      prog[i].style.width = (ski[i] * 2) + '%';
    }
  }

  ani();
});
```

```css
.prog {
  width: 0;
  height: 25px;
  background-color: #C00;
  margin: 0 0 5px;
  transition: width 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div class="prog"></div>
<div class="prog"></div>
<div class="prog"></div>
<div class="prog"></div>
<div class="prog"></div>
<div class="prog"></div>
<div class="prog"></div>
<div class="prog"></div>
```

Comment: This is Javascript only? Assuming you mean you want to animate in JS, then 1) that's a bad idea as CSS performance is *far* better and 2) why have you tagged the question with CSS?

Comment: Your logic needs completely re-writing and you would need to create your own animation routine which changes the widths of the elements on a per-frame basis for the desired length of the animation. That's not 'debugging', that's completely re-writing and massively expanding. The answer I gave above is the most succinct and best way of achieving this.